# How to edit renderRequest parameter in ActionRequest?

Tags: liferay

I've created multilingual aui:input in my .jsp file.

`< aui:model-context bean="<%= object %>" model="<%= SomeClass.class %>" />`
`< aui:input type="text" name="cont"/>`

I have a certain problem with it and that is I'm unable to clear input after submitting the form.
I tried changing render parameters(for all languages) in my ActionRequest, which adds data to database( that's not important though).

`actionResponse.setRenderParameter("cont_en_US", "");`

However, it only work blank fields in my aui:input. If I edit a render parameter in Action Phase for specified language that has some text in aui:input then it gets overwritten by aui:input's value between Action and Render Phase.

Any ideas how to solve this probably simple problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in the action request

actionRequest.setAttribute("mvcPath", "renderAction");

You can access in render request

```
    if(renderRequest.getAttribute("mvcPath")!=null&&renderRequest.getAttribute("mvcPath").equals("renderAction")){
       //do action
    }
```

Because after every action request is performed it goes to render phase.